# How to restore Start menu shortcuts in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, shortcuts, start-screen

Now I can't even get to the Desktop in 8.1 without pressing <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. I also can't get to the Store, OneDrive, or Camera. How can I restore these shortcuts?

If you need more details about how they were removed, if that helps at all, I was installing an application (iDisplay), and when it said what folder to put the Start menu shortcuts in, I typed . for the current directory (the main Start menu directory, instead of an iDisplay folder). It seemed to have emptied the folder, including some of my other shortcuts like Notepad++, Audacity, and BitTorrent.

I already tried doing a System Restore, but it failed because it said it didn't have access to something. I disabled my antivirus (Avast) but it didn't work after a second time.

Answer (score 0):

find a computer using windows 8.1 and copy, on a usb key, the content of  C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs  then copy it back to the same spot on your system.

( I know this is a 2 years old post, but I neded this reply so it may help someone :)  )